# How to create a clickable slideshow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, links

I'm trying to create a slideshow on sharepoint online 2013 that when clicked, brings you to a different page, not just the image itself. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap you can try carousel component. This one we have already on out SPO site.
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

There is another simple example in w3schools also which you can build from scratch and customized as required.

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_rr

You just need to enclosed in an anchor tag in above example as below

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank"><img class="mySlides" src="img_la.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
```

Let me know if you want any additional information on getting information from list and build as a component.

Thanks,
Venkat Konjeti